# Why does ember data store share tokens between 2 web apps my domain?

Tags: nginx, ember.js, proxy

0

I have 2 differents applications in ember.js both connect to the same api: "host1:3000/appA" and "host2:3001/appB". I use nginx so that the client can access appA and appB through a single domain, that is: "mydomain.com/appA" and "mydomain.com/appB". Everything is correct but the applications are sharing "store" ember objects. So if I login into appA, I also login into appB. How can I prevent session sharing between applications?.

I used this code from nginx, but does't work:

```
location /appA {
  proxy_pass http://host1:3000;
  proxy_cookie_path /appA /appA;
}

location /appB {
  proxy_pass http://host2:3001;
  proxy_cookie_path /appB /appB;
}
```

Comment: what is a "store" ember object?

are you using ember-simple-auth on both? is it this kind of store? https://github.com/mainmatter/ember-simple-auth#session-stores  maybe you need a different type of store than you're currently using?

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm going to check that link because the token information is saved in the object:  this.session.data.authenticated. Sorry but I don't know anithing about these projects because belongs to other administrator is not hire anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For at least one of your apps you will want to setup a new session-store.

Create a directory under `app` called `session-stores` and create a file named `application.js`.

The content of this file should be something like this

```js
import AdaptiveStore from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/adaptive';

export default class ApplicationSessionStore extends AdaptiveStore {
  cookieName = 'your-app-name-cookie';
  localStorageKey = 'your-app-name-token';
}
```

This will keep the two apps session data completely separate under a different key. If you're not using the adaptive store (you probably are) then you would extend from the store you are using.

Comment: I'm going to prove it

Comment: but how can I get the 'your-app-name-token' ?

Comment: That is entirely up to you what you name it. These are the keys the app will use to store the session data, so they remain separate between your apps (so long as they have different names). You will still access the session data using `this.session.data.authenticated`